# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'channels')

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, typeerror

I have this small problem where I get the Cannot read properties of undefined error, but I don't know where the issue is. Can someone help me with this one?

Here is the code:

```
const { Client } = require("discord.js");
const DB = require("../Structures/Schemas/LockDown");
/**
 * @param {Client} client
 */
module.exports = async(client) => {
    DB.find().then(async (documentsArray) => {
        documentsArray.forEach(async (d) => {
            const Channel = client.guilds.cache
            .get(d.GuildId)
            .channels.cache.get(d.ChannelID);
            if(!Channel) return;

            const TimeNow = Date.now();
            if(d.Time < TimeNow){
            Channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(d.GuildID, {
                SEND_MESSAGES: null,
            });
            return await DB.deleteOne({ ChannelID: Channel.id });
        }

            const ExpireDate = d.time - Date.now();

            setTimeout(async () => {
                Channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(d.GuildID, {
                    SEND_MESSAGES: null,
                });
                await DB.deleteOne({ ChannelID: Channel.id });
            }, ExpireDate);
        });
    });
};
```

and here is the error I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'channels')
```

Comment: Well `client.guilds.cache.get(d.GuildId)` returns `undefined`. So the `.channels` call leads to the Typeerror.
Use a debugger to check why it is undefined, because we cannot help you without knowing the data etc.

Comment: just after the lign `documentsArray.forEach(async (d) => {`, add a `console.log(d)` and edit your answer talling us what does it show you on the console, maybe you made a typo like it's `guildID` or `GUILDID`.

Comment: If my answer worked, make sure to mark it as the best answer! You can also upvote if you are not the owner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a chance that not all channels and guilds are added to the cache. Try fetching them first and then see. For example, something like this should work:

```js
const { Client } = require('discord.js');
const DB = require('../Structures/Schemas/LockDown');
/**
 * @param {Client} client
 */
module.exports = async(client) => {
    DB.find().then(async(documentsArray) => {
        documentsArray.forEach(async(d) => {
            const GuildChannel = await client.guilds.fetch(d.GuildId);
            const Channel = await GuildChannel.channels.fetch(d.ChannelID);
            if (!Channel) return;

            const TimeNow = Date.now();
            if (d.Time < TimeNow) {
                Channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(d.GuildID, {
                    SEND_MESSAGES: null,
                });
                return await DB.deleteOne({
                    ChannelID: Channel.id
                });
            }

            const ExpireDate = d.time - Date.now();

            setTimeout(async() => {
                Channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(d.GuildID, {
                    SEND_MESSAGES: null,
                });
                await DB.deleteOne({
                    ChannelID: Channel.id
                });
            }, ExpireDate);
        });
    });
};
```

Instead of fetching the guild and then the channel, directly fetch the channel from the client like so:

```js
const { Client } = require('discord.js');
const DB = require('../Structures/Schemas/LockDown');
/**
 * @param {Client} client
 */
module.exports = async(client) => {
    DB.find().then(async(documentsArray) => {
        documentsArray.forEach(async(d) => {
            const Channel = await client.channels.fetch(d.ChannelID);
            if (!Channel) return;

            const TimeNow = Date.now();
            if (d.Time < TimeNow) {
                Channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(d.GuildID, {
                    SEND_MESSAGES: null,
                });
                return await DB.deleteOne({
                    ChannelID: Channel.id
                });
            }

            const ExpireDate = d.time - Date.now();

            setTimeout(async() => {
                Channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(d.GuildID, {
                    SEND_MESSAGES: null,
                });
                await DB.deleteOne({
                    ChannelID: Channel.id
                });
            }, ExpireDate);
        });
    });
};
```

Or, as [@Malik Lahlou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17010560/malik-lahlou) said, it could be a typo.

#### Resources:

- [`ChannelManager.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch)
- [`GuildManager.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildManager?scrollTo=fetch)

**Hoped this helped!**

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it fixed my issue!