# Why is my terminal not letting me run node index.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I tried to run node index.js in terminal but this error came up: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Guilds'). The following is my code:

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    if (interaction.commandName === '!help') {
        await interaction.reply('I dont want to haelp u');
    }
});

client.login('OTQ0NjQyMDQ3MTI0NTgyNTEw.YhEkdg.e2AspV6x5JtTqKkq24DkeMmDlSo');
```

Comment: Where does `GatewayIntentBits` come from?

Comment: @Ivar This is based on the example code in the [README](//github.com/discordjs/discord.js/#example-usage).

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71234902/typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-channels

Comment: @SebastianSimon I see. Looks like a very recent change. It's part of [14.0.0-dev](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js/v/14.0.0-dev.1645876999.a8321d8), but not of the latest stable version ([13.6.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js/v/13.6.0)). I'm going to assume that OP isn't using the latest dev version of Discord.js.

Comment: Now anyone can use your token, you might want to ask to redact this question if you care about it. Token is like password, something you should not share with anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is an issue with the Intent. Since you have not provided the error output, I suggest you to use

```
 
 ​   ​const​ ​{​Client​,​ Intents​,​ Collection​}​ ​=​ ​require​(​'discord.js'​) 
 ​   ​const​ ​client​ ​=​ ​new​ ​Client​(​{​intents​:​[​Intents​.​FLAGS​.​GUILDS​,​Intents​.​FLAGS​.​GUILD_MESSAGES​]​}​)
```

Replace this code with your first two lines of code which is :

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });
```

And please don't share bot Token ever. Its like login Credentials for your bot. Please reset it on your discord developer console.